# Placement of "other" in "other than" construct

Tags: grammar

I work in translation (Japanese to English) and come across the construct "other [noun] than" in many translations done by Japanese native speakers. To me (native Australian English speaker), this sounds really awkward and I always change it to "[noun] other than", but I'm beginning to doubt whether or not this needs changing.

As an example, please refer to the following, slightly modified, sentence:

> The entry with "0" as a base refers to an area allocated to other
>   entities than the LPAR.

Is the above usage grammatically correct? Could this be an AE/BE difference?

Comment: To entities other than x. But you should be asking this on Japanes>English lists or forums, on other sites. Other [noun] than is wrong to my ears.

Comment: I also work in J-E translation. "other Xs than Y" is no good. Change it. "other dogs than poodles"? No. "dogs other than poodles" and so on.

Comment: I have no comment on the translation, not knowing Japanese.

‘Other dogs than poodles’ and ‘dogs other than poodles’ can both be right but they aren’t often interchangeable; one difference being that ‘other dogs’ might be more inclusive and ‘dogs other’ exclusive.

‘Other dogs than poodles often have curly hair, too.’

‘Dogs other than huskies can’t pull sledges’

‘Other dogs than corgis also make good pets.’

‘Dogs other than terriers are too big to go ratting’

‘Other dogs than spaniels can have floppy ears.’

‘Dogs other than St Bernards get stuck in the snow’